# mysql select between or what?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm learning about MySQL and I have a case, I have some table like this:

```
id, level,        minpost, maxpost
 1, 'Newbie',           0,      99
 2, 'Enthusiast',     100,     499
 3, 'Activist',       500,     749
 4, 'Socialite',      750,     999
```

So how do I know which "level" if I have **80** posts?

Should I use select between or maybe you have any suggest for my problem?

ps. I cant post image :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT level FROM <table> WHERE <myLevel> BETWEEN minpost AND maxpost
```

The [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator will do the following:

```
expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

Equals:

```
(min <= expr AND expr <= max)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from the_table
where 80 between minpost AND maxpost
```

P.S.: don't bother posting images, SQL code (that can be copied) is much better

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use BETWEEN.

It's nothing but the short form of `value>=minvalue AND value<=maxvalue`

The query will look like:

```
select * from `tableName`
   where <valueToCheck> between minpost AND maxpost;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,level from <table> where minpost >= <minpost> and maxpost <= <maxpost>
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to find rows between value range. He wants to find a row for which value is within the range of minpost and maxpost.

Comment: I'm not saying this will not work but this is not what OP wants as far as I understand his question. You are assuming to have 2 values in where condition `<minpost>` and `<maxpost>` while OP has only one.

Comment: I thought it has this schema (id, level,,minpost, maxpost) with minpost and maxpost as two columns.

Comment: yes you are right. You are taking me wrong. You query should look like: `select id,level from <table> where post >= minpost and post <= maxpost`